# Kohana 3.2 Routing and subdomains problem

Tags: php, routes, kohana, subdomain

I have subdomain www.panel.example.com and domain www.example.com.

My bootstrap.php:

```
<?php 
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/',
        'index_file' => FALSE,
));

Route::set('panel', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))', array('subdomain' => 'panel'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'panel',
        'controller' => 'panel',
        'action'     => 'index',
        'subdomain'  => 'panel',
    ));
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'home',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
?>
```

When I'm writing adress on browser: www.panel.example.com I have an error:

```
HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

My structure:

application/classes/controller (controllers of domain)

application/classes/controller/panel (controllers of subdomain)

How to do it properly?

Comment: Are you working with any hosting software like Cpanel or Plesk? By the wy, `www.panel.example.com`, shouldn't be `panel.example.com` ?

Comment: I use hosting software DirectAdmin and I created subdomain panel.example.com

Comment: `Kohana` has no built-in method for `subdomains`, but you can read the uri on the `bootstrap.php` and catch the `subdomain` name and re-route the `uri`.

Comment: Here's an example on how I did it with `v3.1.x` : http://pastebin.com/3Q4YbLWq (the code is a bit messy, but the idea is there, and it worked). Note that the procedure might change depending on how your hosting software creates the subdomains (`cPanel` for instance creates the subdomains as a folder in `public_html`, while `Plesk` creates them in `subdomains\name` outside `httpdocs`)

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in way to deal with subdomains in routes. So my suggestion comes from searching the internet:

One way to do this is get the subdomain from the `SERVER` global:

```
list($subdomain) = explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 2);
```

Then, call a controller or directory in the route based on this subdomain:

```
Route::set('panel', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
  ->defaults(array(
    'directory'  => $subdomain,
    'controller' => 'panel',
    'action'     => 'index',
  ));
```

Or use lambda/callback routes for more flexibility when handling the subdomain: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing#lambdacallback-route-logic

This answer is based on using different templates for different subdomains: [kohana v3: using different templates for different subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764543/kohana-v3-using-different-templates-for-different-subdomains)

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to check if subdomain route need to be set.

```
//Set an array with subdomains and Configs
$arrDomainsDirectories = array(
    'services'=>array(
        'subdomain'=>'services',
        'directory'=>'Services',
        'controller' => 'Home',
        'action'     => 'index'
    ),
    'default'=>array(
        'subdomain'=>NULL,
        'directory'=>'',
        'controller' => 'Home',
        'action'     => 'index'
    )
);

//Config Route based on SERVER_NAME
$subdomain = explode('.', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 2);

//If Not Subdomain set Default
if(count($subdomain) <= 1){
    $subdomain = 'default';
} else {
    $subdomain = $subdomain[0];
}

$routeConfig = $arrDomainsDirectories[$subdomain];

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))', array('subdomain'=>$routeConfig['subdomain']))
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => $routeConfig['directory'],
        'controller' => $routeConfig['controller'],
        'action'     => $routeConfig['action']
    ));
```